# Nginx rtmp exec_push

Tags: node.js, nginx, ffmpeg, rtmp

I have 2 nginx instances and 1 node server with each running on separate VM.
The first instance get the rtmp stream.
The second instance is the HLS app.
The node server execute the ffmpeg script and send the combined stream to instance 2.

What I want is to execute ffmpeg with exec_push from instance 1 on the node server. I tried curl but it's not enough because he just receives the response.

Nginx config :

```
rtmp {
  server {
     listen 1935;
     ping 30s;
     notify_method get;

        application ingest {
             live on;
             exec_kill_signal term;
             idle_streams off;
             exec_push curl -s IP:3000/$name ;
             #exec_push /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg_push.sh $name ;
           }
  }
}
```

NodeJS

```
app.get('/:name', (req, res) =>{

        const testscript = exec('sh /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg_push.sh '+ req.params.name);
        testscript.stdout.on('data', function(data){
                 console.log('\x1b[32m', data);
                // sendBackInfo();
        });

        testscript.stderr.on('data', function(data){
                console.log("\x1b[31m", data);
                // triggerErrorStuff();
        });

        testscript.on('close', function (code){
                console.log("\x1b[31m", {data: {status: 'error', code: code}});
        });
})

app.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0', () => console.log("\x1b[32m", 'ok on port 3000'))
```

Do you have any hint or idea please ?
Thank you